# Running VBA on footnote text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA and managed to put together a simple macro that will convert all text with a certain style to a hyperlink (pasted below), and I would really like it to do the same thing with all footnote text as well, but none of the answers online I've tried have worked so far.

Any thoughts?

```
Sub FindLinkStyle()
Dim strStyle As String
strStyle = "Subtle Reference"
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
    .text = ""
    .ClearFormatting
    .Style = strStyle
        Do While .Execute
        ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
        Address:="#link"
        Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the Word UI, "Find" works only on the "Story" you specify. So in your case it will depend on where `Selection` is. To specifically address Footnotes, see how a Range object is set to the "footnotes story" in the following code sample, then that Range used in a Find.

```
Sub FindInFootnote()
    Dim rngFT As word.Range

    Set rngFT = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFootnotesStory)
    With rngFT.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Style = "Subtle Reference"
        .Replacement.Text = "XXXXX!!!!!"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```